# Does "alter" means "change into something worse"?

Tags: meaning, translation

In French, the verb *altérer* means *change into something worse* or *degrade*. As a non-native English speaker I wonder whether the English verb *alter* has necessarily this negative meaning or in the contrary, if it is neutral as *change* or *transform*.

Comment: Short answer - no, it just means change, not necessarily into something worse

Comment: This is a fair question, but one that probably should have been asked at the sister site for [ell.SE].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is generally neutral.

- "Please alter your attitude." would mean to *improve* your attitude, by context.
- "I must remember to alter the path by which I drive to work every day."

Answer (score 5):

*Alter* on its own has no positive or negative connotations. For example,

> His character **altered** so much that I could not believe it was him

could mean he changed in a positive way, negative way, or simply a neutral way that made him very different from before.

Answer (score 3):

The verb *alter* is often used to describe the process of [making changes to clothing](http://www.alter-to-fit.com.au/) in order to improve the fit for a particular customer.

I wonder if native speakers of French avoid such businesses?

Comment: What he said: while most meanings of *alter* are completely neutral, there is this one meaning which is completely *positive*. There are no meanings that are negative.